# Solve for A. $\Bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}9&9\\-9&0\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr]=4A-\Bigl[\begin{smallmatrix}2&-2\\0&2\end{smallmatrix}\Bigr]A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I didn't know how to evaluate
$$4A-\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-2 \\ 
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}A$$

and so I looked in the solutions, and what they did was they rewrote $4A$ as

$$\begin{bmatrix}
4 &0 \\ 
0 & 4
\end{bmatrix}A-\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-2 \\ 
0 & 2
\end{bmatrix}A$$

Is this allowed? Why does this work?

Comment: Have you tired to do it in components?

Comment: It's 4 multiplied by the identity matrix x A

Comment: It works by the **definition** of [scalar multiplication of matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication#Scalar_multiplication_of_matrices).

Comment: Assuming A is a 2x2 matrix (which it must be for the expression to make sense) then 4A = 4(I$\times$ A)= (4I)A$ and $4I $ is the the matrix wit 4 in its diagonal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A=IA$ and $kI = \begin{bmatrix} k & 0 \\ 0 & k \end{bmatrix}$ for all $k$, so it follows that
$$4A = 4IA = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 4 \end{bmatrix}A$$

Comment: The identity $4(IA)=(4I)A$ is implicitly used, which is not obvious and one might eventually end up with proving $4A=4(IA)$ by definition.

Comment: @Jack: I don't see the problem. Obvious or not, when doing matrix algebra (like in this question), it is fine to assume basic rules of matrix multiplication and scalar multiplication without re-proving them every time.

Comment: Surely my comment was not an objection to your answer. "it is fine to assume basic rules of matrix multiplication and scalar multiplication without re-proving them every time" I would assume that this is not a suggestion for one who does not know the "basic rules" or does not know the necessity of these rules (yet).

Answer (score 1):

It follows from the **definition** of [scalar multiplication of matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_multiplication#Scalar_multiplication_of_matrices):

$$
k\begin{pmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
ka&kb\\
kc&kd
\end{pmatrix}.
$$ 
By this definition, for any $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ and any scalar $k$, one can check by direct calculation that
$$
kA=(kI)A.
$$
Of course one can write 
$$
kA=k(IA)=(kI)A,
$$
if one knows

- how $kI$ is defined
- why one has "associativity" in the second identity.